# Exception: "No such driver version {browser_version} for {platform}"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web

I tried to download Selenium WebDriver, (using Python 3.11), but it raises this error:

```
Exception(f"No such driver version {browser_version} for {platform}")
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do not post errors or codes in screenshot. Copy & paste into your question. Also, you should show more context of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method in your screenshot: [get_url_for_version_and_platform()](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/blob/05ffbe94608d06be7a62ac9e3b3f3cc9b9540629/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py#L67), I can see that you're using `WebDriverManager` to download drivers. That library has been deprecated in favor of Selenium Manager, which is now fully operational in `selenium` `4.10.0` (and newer) for downloading drivers as needed.

This is all you need now:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

---

If you're wondering why you're now seeing this error for `ChromeDriverManager`, it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

Answer (score 0):

you may need this method i guess.

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_version ='114.0.5735.90'

service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_version).install())

Comment: This is bad practice.